# Race Condition Check

Tags: qt, qml

I have provided below my code in Qt 5.6(QML). I wanted to send the data when the slider value changes and also to send the same data every 2.5 secs when the slider is not moving. As a heart beat from the app to my hardware. I have made provisions in my code to handle Race condition but just wanted some review to see if all the conditions have been taken care of.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import sertransclient 1.0

Rectangle {
    id:root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    //color: "#90a4ae"
    gradient: Gradient{
        GradientStop{position: 0.0; color: "#101B4D"}
        GradientStop{position: 0.2; color: "#101B4D"}
        GradientStop{position: 0.25; color: "#101B4D"}
        GradientStop{position: 0.4; color: "#0D113D"}
        GradientStop{position: 0.5; color: "#0F1545"}
        GradientStop{position: 0.6; color: "#0B2767"}
        GradientStop{position: 1.0; color: "#064A99"}
    }
    property int slider_value:0.0
    property int prev_slider:11
    property string txPacket;
    property bool usbAttached: false
    property int data_lock:0
    property int timer_data:0
    function buildTxPacket(){
        if(root.usbAttached===true)
        {
            if(timer_data==0)
            {
                if(slider_value!==prev_slider)
                {

                    txPacket="VA="+slider_value+'\r'+'\n';
                    serTransClient.txData=txPacket;
                    data_lock=0;
                    prev_slider=slider_value;
                }
            }

            else if(timer_data==1)
            {
                txPacket="VA="+slider_value+'\r'+'\n';
                serTransClient.txData=txPacket;
                timer_data=0;
                data_lock=0;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            if(slider_value!==prev_slider)
            {
                console.log("Not Attached");
                console.log(slider_value);
                prev_slider=slider_value;
            }
        }

    }




    SerTransClient{
        id:serTransClient
        objectName: "stc"
        onDeviceAttached: {
            serTransClient.notifyData="MCP 2200 attached";
            serTransClient.baudRate=SerTransClient.Baud115200;
            serTransClient.dataBits=SerTransClient.Data8;
            serTransClient.stopBits=SerTransClient.OneStop;
            serTransClient.parity=SerTransClient.None;
            serTransClient.flowControl=SerTransClient.NoFlowControl;
            serTransClient.setLineCoding();
            root.usbAttached=true;
        }
        onDeviceNotAttached: {
            serTransClient.notifyData="MCP 2200 not attached";
            root.usbAttached=false;
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id: slider1
        width: parent.width/8
        height: parent.height/1.4
        z: 1
        anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 1
        anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: 0
        enabled: true
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        orientation: Qt.Vertical
        minimumValue:0.0
        maximumValue:10.0
        updateValueWhileDragging: true
        stepSize: 0.1
        value:0.0
        style: SliderStyle{
            groove:Rectangle{
                implicitHeight: slider1.width-20
                implicitWidth: slider1.height
                LinearGradient{
                    anchors.fill:parent
                    start: Qt.point(0,0)
                    end:Qt.point(slider1.width,slider1.width)
                    gradient: Gradient{
                        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#110E2C" }
                        GradientStop { position: 0.4; color: "#333358" }
                        GradientStop { position: 0.8; color: "#555573" }
                        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#CFCFD7" }
                    }
                }

            }
            handle:
                Rectangle{
                id:recthandle
                implicitWidth: 2*(slider1.width/8)
                implicitHeight: slider1.width+20
                radius: 12
                color:"transparent"
                Text{
                    color: "red"
                    width:slider1.width/8
                    height:slider1.width+20
                    anchors.top: recthandle.top
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    text:slider_value+"%"
                    rotation: 90
                    font.family: "Times New Roman"
                    font.pixelSize:2*(slider1.width/8)
                }
                Rectangle{
                    id:recthandle2
                    anchors.bottom: recthandle.bottom
                    color:"red"
                    border.color: "gray"
                    border.width: 2
                    implicitWidth: slider1.width/8
                    implicitHeight: slider1.width+20
                    radius: 12

                }

            }


        }
        onValueChanged:{
            data_lock=1;
            slider_value=(value*10).toFixed(1);
            root.buildTxPacket()

        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle1
        width:slider1.width
        height:slider1.height+5
        color: "#ffffff"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        radius: 8
        border.width: 0
    }

    Image {
        id: image1
        width: (root.width/6.4)
        height: (root.height/9.6)
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 31
        source: "Image/Back Arrow.png"
    }

    Image {
        id: image2
        width: (root.width/6.4)
        height: (root.height/4.8)
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 20
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        source: "Image/SFC Logo 2.png"
    }

    Timer{
        interval: 2500
        running: true
        repeat:true

        onTriggered: {
            if(data_lock==0)
            {
                timer_data=1;
                console.log("Timer_Data");
                console.log(slider_value)
                root.buildTxPacket();
            }


        }

    }
}
```

To break down my code function `buildTxPacket()` is being accessed by both the `slider` and `Timer`. I want to avoid a situation where either one of them is blocking the other.

Right now I think that is taken care of.

Any suggestion to improve my race handling situation is welcomed.